# MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE csv ignore primary field insertion

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am trying to import a csv file into a table in mysql. The table has these fields:

(`id`, `Submission ID`, `User ID`, `Submission Date and Time`,  `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `Participant's HQ / Agency`)

But the csv file has every fields except `id`. `id` field is `Primary` and `Auto incremental`. I tried to use a variable in order to 'bypass' importing the first field so my code is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\imports\\tf\\output_csv.csv' INTO TABLE form_tf (@id, `Submission ID`, `User ID`, `Submission Date and Time`,  `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `Participant's HQ / Agency`)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But it is not inserting `Submission ID` so all fields are shifted to the left by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `id` (primary key - auto incremental) to `null`, like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\imports\\tf\\output_csv.csv' INTO TABLE form_tf 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(`Submission ID`, `User ID`, `Submission Date and Time`,  `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `Participant's HQ / Agency`)
set id = NULL;
```